# can't get a picture from different links

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have express server and special folder for images.

```
app.use(express.static("files"));
```

And if I try to get an image, for example, in localhost:3000/test from the files folder, it works. But if I try to get an image for example in localhost:3000/profile/404 from the same folder - it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Change the path of public to:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname +"/files"));`
And make sure you access the files with absolute paths from client:

```
<img src="/profile/404.png" />
```

On server:
files --> profile --> 404.png